# Typing map of functions calls

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm having troubles typing a function that gets called using `ACTIONS_MAP`. I'm getting a "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature." in the `ACTIONS_MAP[action.type](action);` line.

What I think its happening is that `fetchAction`, `navigateAction`, and `openModalAction` each expect an `action` argument with its respective type. So at compile TS can't be 100% sure that I'm passing the right type to each action function.

```
import { fetchAction, FetchAction } from './fetch';
import { navigateAction, NavigateAction } from './navigate';
import { openModalAction, OpenModalAction } from './openModal';

const ACTIONS_MAP = {
  $fetch: fetchAction,
  $navigate: navigateAction,
  $openModal: openModalAction,
};

export type Action =
  | FetchAction
  | NavigateAction
  | OpenModalAction;

export function dispatchActions(actions: Action[]) {
  actions.forEach(action => {
    ACTIONS_MAP[action.type](action);
  });
}
```

Is there a way to type this or what's a good alternative to this approach?

Edit:
Here is a contrived example of `fetch.ts` the other ones are similar.

```
export interface FetchAction {
    type: '$fetch';
    // More types here
}


export function fetchAction(action: FetchAction) {
    // Do some work here
}
```

Comment: Could you include the imported code?

Comment: @jcalz Added a simplified example, hope it helps

Comment: Wow, this is fun.  I don't think I have a practical solution other than just tell the type system not to worry (e.g., `as any` somewhere).  The ideal solution would require something like [existential types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466) where you could quantify over constituents of the `Action` union without having to consider each one separately.

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying to avoid the `switch`: `switch(action.type) {
        case "$fetch" : ACTIONS_MAP[action.type](action); break;
        case "$navigate" : ACTIONS_MAP[action.type](action); break;
        case "$openModal" : ACTIONS_MAP[action.type](action); break;
    }` ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yes, I'm trying to avoid the switch if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to avoid using a switch in this case (at least that I can think of) it to use a type assertion. While not ideal, sometimes type assertion are necessary in Typescript code, although we should use them only when absolutely necessary:

```
type ActionHandler = (a: Action)=> void;
export function dispatchActions(actions: Action[]) {
    actions.forEach(action => {
        (ACTIONS_MAP[action.type] as ActionHandler)(action);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to pass around references to the action functions themselves, you could try something like this as the practical solution:

```js
type FooAction = {
  type: '$foo';
  payload: string;
}

type BlahAction = {
  type: '$blah';
  payload: number;
}

type Action = FooAction | BlahAction;

function fooAction(action: FooAction) {
  console.log(action.payload);
}

function blahAction(action: BlahAction) {
  console.log(action.payload + 1)
}

const dispatchAction = (action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case '$foo':
      // TS knows action must be a FooAction
      return fooAction(action);
    case '$blah':
      // TS knows action must be a BlahAction
      return blahAction(action);
    default:
      return;
  }
}

function dispatchActions(actions: Action[]) {
  actions.forEach(action => {
    dispatchAction(action);
  });
}

dispatchActions([
  { type: "$foo", payload: 'bar' },
  { type: "$blah", payload: 1 }
])
```

This gets you type checking in all the right places (I think). Once you leave each given `case` statement, though, you lose the type narrowing information. So you can't just return the function and then call it later.